# Determinant of a matrix without actually expanding it.

Tags: determinant

Given a Matrix $$A =  \begin{vmatrix}
a^2 & (s-a)^2 & (s-a)^2\\
(s-b)^2 & b^2 & (s-b)^2 \\
(s-c)^2 & (s-c)^2 & c^2\\ 
\end{vmatrix}$$

and $$a+b+c = 2s$$ , how can I find its determinant without expanding?

I've tried finding all factors which make two columns (/rows) similar or proportional. Only with `s=0` all the rows and columns becomes `1` (after taking out the common value). With `s=a` $$\left|\matrix{
a^2 & 0 & 0\\
(a-b)^2=c^2 & b^2 & (a-b)^2=c^2 \\
(a-c)^2=b^2 & (a-c)^2=b^2 & c^2\\ 
}\right|=0$$

Here is a list of trivial factors
`(s-a), (s-b), (s-c), (s-0)`. I'm given a hint that the determinant is a degree 6 polynomial, which I don't understand cause max degree of `s` is 4, please do explain how degree is 6.

I think `det(A) = (s-a)(s-b)(s-c)(s-0)`.

Are there any more factors? What are they?

Edit: Please also explain how to arrive at the solution.

Comment: Try to evaluate the determinant at $s=a,b$ or $c$. It is likely that you will find 0 or something which will give you some hints about the zeros of the degree six determinant. A naive guess would be that the determinant is something like $(s-a)^2(s-b)^2(s-c)^2$.

Comment: Seing Jan Eerland post, my naive guess seems to be a bit too naive!

Comment: I've tried replacing $$s=a$$ and found the above matrix [second one in question], I don't understand how the degree is 6 when there are 3 variables.

Comment: @SirDevil Each component is of degree $2$, so $A$ is of degree $6$.

Comment: It's of degree $6$ in $\ s\ $, which you can see from the third term, $ (s-a)^2\big((s-b)^2(s-c)^2-b^2(s-c)^2 \big)\ $, in the expansion of the determinant by the first row.

Comment: @lonzaleggiera can't upvote yet, thanx

Comment: https://www.toppr.com/ask/question/if-2s-a-b-c-beginvmatrixa2-s-a2-s/ . Check it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The equation $a+b+c=2s$ has a geometric interpretation: $s$ is the semiperimeter of a triangle of sides $a,\,b,\,c$. If this triangle is degenerate, say with $a=b+c$, then $s=a$ and$$A=\left|\begin{array}{ccc}
\left(b+c\right)^{2} & 0 & 0\\
c^{2} & b^{2} & c^{2}\\
b^{2} & b^{2} & c^{2}
\end{array}\right|=0,$$so $(s-a)(s-b)(s-c)|A$. A similar treatment of $-a=b+c\implies s=0$ can prove $s|A$. Since $A$ is of dimension $6$ and is homogeneous when all sides are rescaled, the symmetries require a result proportional to $s^3(s-a)(s-b)(s-c)$. An equilateral triangle with $a=b=c=2,\,s=3,\,A=54$ proves the coefficient is $2$, as in @JanEerland's answer.

Comment: could you explain how A has 6 dimension? And in $(s-a)(s-b)(s-c)|A$ what does $|A$ means?

Comment: @SirDevil I explained its dimension in a comment under the OP. $|$ denotes oine polynomial dividing another.

Comment: Is there any other way to understand (besides symmetries) why $s^2$ should be a factor and not say $(s-c_{1}) (s-c_{2})$?

Comment: @SirDevil We determine factors by finding when $A=0$, not by using symmetries.

Answer (score 1):

> Not a 'real' answer, but it was too big for a comment.

I wrote and ran some [Mathematica](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wolfram_Mathematica)-code:

```
In[1]:=Clear["Global`*"];
FullSimplify[
 Det[{{a^2, (s - a)^2, (s - a)^2}, {(s - b)^2, 
    b^2, (s - b)^2}, {(s - c)^2, (s - c)^2, c^2}}], 
 Assumptions -> a + b + c == 2 s]
```

Running the code gives:

```
Out[1]=-2 (b - s) (b + c - s) s^3 (-c + s)
```

If you're not only looking for the solution, it is not very hard to show that this is correct.

Comment: You sure this was too big to fit in the comments?

Comment: Since $b+c-s=2s-a-s=s-a$, it's more helpful to write this as $2s^3(s-a)(s-b)(s-c)$, making the symmetries obvious.

Comment: But how to arrive at this without a computer assist?